# Vowpal Wabbit: Input of neural network?

Tags: neural-network, vowpalwabbit

In the machine learning tool vowpal wabbit  (https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/), normally a linear estimator y*=wx is trained. However, it is possible to add a forward neural.

My question is: When I use the neural network by the command line option "-nn x", is the linear estimator wx completely replaced by an neural network?

Edit: Thanks Martin and arielf. So apperently the different constellations look like this:

[image]

The weights of the models with "--nn" are estimated by backpropagation?

Comment: Thanks so much for the work on the diagrams.  It makes everything clearer.  Labeling the NN graph edges with the corresponding weights in the models `wF[N]` (which as Martin mentioned in the comments are not all represented in the `--invert-hash` output) would make it even clearer. `wF[N]` is the weight from feature `F` to layer node `N`. The weights from the hidden-layer to the output node are apparently not shown in `--invert-hash`.

Answer (score 4):

[**Edit:** corrected answer: original wasn't accurate, thanks Martin]

The 1-layer NN feeds input features into the NN layer (all possible interactions) which are then fed to the output layer.

In order to add pass-through features as-is, without interactions, you should add the `--inpass` option.

You can look at models created by using `--invert_hash` to get a readable model on a small example:

```
$ cat dat.vw
1 | a b
2 | a c

# default linear model, no NN:
$ vw --invert_hash dat.ih dat.vw
...

$ cat dat.ih
...
:0
Constant:116060:0.387717
a:92594:0.387717
b:163331:0.193097
c:185951:0.228943

# Now add --nn 2 (note double-dash in long option)
# to use a 1-layer NN with 2 nodes
$ vw --nn 2 --invert_hash dat-nn.ih dat.vw
...

$ cat dat-nn.ih
...
:0
Constant:202096:-0.270493
Constant[1]:202097:0.214776
a:108232:-0.270493
a[1]:108233:0.214776
b:129036:-0.084952
b[1]:129037:0.047303
c:219516:-0.196927
c[1]:219517:0.172029
```

Looks like `a[N]` is the contribution of `a` to hidden-layer NN node `N` (starting with base/index zero apparently, the standalone `a` notation is a bit confusing).

When you add `--inpass` you get an additional weight per feature (index [2]):

```
$ vw --nn 2 --inpass --invert_hash dat-nn-ip.ih dat.vw
...
$ cat dat-nn-ip.ih
...
:0
Constant:202096:-0.237726
Constant[1]:202097:0.180595
Constant[2]:202098:0.451169
a:108232:-0.237726
a[1]:108233:0.180595
a[2]:108234:0.451169
b:129036:-0.084570
b[1]:129037:0.047293
b[2]:129038:0.239481
c:219516:-0.167271
c[1]:219517:0.139488
c[2]:219518:0.256326
```

Comment: I thought the original features are used only with `--inpass` (I cannot test it right now).

Comment: Interesting, `--inpass` adds 3 more features to the model `a[2]`, `b[2]`, and `c[2]`.  I'm not sure what exactly do they mean.

Comment: I checked briefly the source code nn.cc. With `--nn N`, we have N units in the hidden layer and N parameters for each feature, which are in `--invert_hash` marked as, e.g. `a` and `a[1]`. Then there are N additional parameters, for the output layer (connections between the N hidden units and final prediction output unit), but these are unfortunately not reported in `--audit` and `--invert_hash`. So for F features, we need to train have F*N + N parameters, but only F*N parameters are shown in `--invert_hash` model.

Comment: With `--nn N --inpass`, the input units (i.e. input features) are connected directly with the output unit (in addition to the connections via hidden layer units), so there are FN+N+F parameters, but only FN+F are shown in the `--invert_hash` model. The `a[2]` you see, is the parameter for the direct (inpass) connection.

Comment: Has there been any new argument since then to print all the FN+N (or FN+N+F for `--inpass`) weights for -nn flag ? Seems like an important feature to understand and visualize the neural network.